# Set multiple call backs on rails controller action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, tdd, dry

I have two call backs on one method, here is my code:

```
before_action :set_foo, only: :foo 
before_action -> {set_bar @bar }, only: :foo 

def foo; end
```

Is there anyway I can shorten this so that I only have to call before_action once?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple "names" to [`before_action`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods.html#method-i-before_action):

```
before_action :set_foo, -> { set_bar @bar }, only: foo
```

The options to `before_action` (`only: :foo` in this case) apply to all the "names". The documentation is explicit on what the "names" can be but, like the rest of the callbacks in Rails, they can be anything "callable": method names, procs, lambdas, ...

Comment: I wish the documents were a bit clearer because they show a signature of `before_action(names,block)` but the actual signature is `before_action(*names,&blk)` which makes it much more obvious that it accepts multiple names and an optional block. Even if "names" implies multiple I would assume based on the documented signature that this would be `before_action [:set_foo,-> { set_bar @bar }]` and I would have no idea how to pass options because it looks like the second argument is a) mandatory; b) positional. Nevertheless this answer is absolutely correct

Comment: @engineersmnky You could probably put a period (or even an exclamation mark) right after "I wish the documents were a bit clearer". So much of Rails is fiddling with things to see what works and reading the source to fill in missing bits. OTOH, I haven't submitted any pull requests to flesh out the docs so...

Comment: On a slightly unrelated note are methods/functions an instance of another Ruby class?

Comment: @CJG `->{}.class` says `Proc` and `'s'.method(:length).class` says `Method` so yes. Unless I misunderstand the question.

Comment: @CJG since everything in ruby is an object there is technically no such thing as a function, there are only methods (message transmissions). The answer to "are [insert anything here] an instance of another Ruby class." is yes because everything is an instance of a ruby class. Even classes are instances of a ruby class. This creates terminological confusion to some extent since things like "class methods" are actually technically instance methods of an instance of the class `Class`.